# R - Extract information from string following a general format

Tags: r, regex, string

This is a complete re-write of my original question in an attempt to clarify it and make it as answerable as possible. My objective is to write a function which takes a string as input and returns the information contained therein in tabular format. Two examples of the kind of character strings the function will face are the following

```
s1 <- "  9 9875     Γεωργίου Άγγελος Δημήτρης       ΑΒ/Γ  Π/Π Β   00:54:05          167***\r"
s2 <- " 10 8954F    Smith John                      ΔΕΖ   N       ΔΕΝ ΕΚΚΙΝΗΣΕ        0\r"
```

(For those who had read my original question, these are smaller strings for simplicity.)

The **required output** would be:

```
 Rank  Code                      Name Club Class         Time Points
    9  9875 Γεωργίου Άγγελος Δημήτρης ΑΒ/Γ Π/Π Β     00:54:05    167
   10 8954F                Smith John  ΔΕΖ     N ΔΕΝ ΕΚΚΙΝΗΣΕ      0
```

I have managed to split the string based on where there's a blank space using:

`strsplit(s1, " ")[[1]][strsplit(s1, " ")[[1]] != ""]`

although a more elegant solution was given by G. Grothendieck in the comments below using:

`unlist(strsplit(trimws(s1), " +"))`

This results in

`"9" "9875" "Γεωργίου" "Άγγελος" "Δημήτρης" "ΑΒ/Γ" "Π/Π" "Β" "00:54:05" "167***\r"`

However, this is still problematic as `"Γεωργίου" "Άγγελος"` and `"Δημήτρης"` should be combined into `"Γεωργίου Άγγελος Δημήτρης"` (note that the number of elements could be two OR three) and the same applies to `"Π/Π" "Β"` which should be combined into `"Π/Π Β"`.

**The question**

How can I use the additional information that I have, namely:

- The order of the elements will always be the same
- The `Name` data will consist of two or three words
- The `Club` data (i.e. `ΑΒ/Γ` in `s1` and `ΔΕΖ` in `s2`) will come from a pre-defined list of clubs (e.g. stored in a character vector named `sClub`)
- The `Class` data (i.e. `Π/Π Β` in `s1` and `N` in `s2`) will come from a pre-defined list of classes (e.g. stored in a character vector named `sClass`)
- The `Points` data will always contain "\r" and won't contain any spaces.

to produce the required output above?

Comment: You can use a regular expression with `strcapture` or `unlist(strsplit(trimws(s1), "  +"))` will get you most of the way there where the pattern is two spaces and a plus.

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work? What did you get? What did you expect?
What doesn't work with your code and where is it?

Comment: This is as far as I got `strsplit(s1, " ")[[1]][strsplit(s1, " ")[[1]] != ""]` but I don't know how to utilise the structure of the text to my advantage,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Defining

```
sClub <- c("ΑΒ/Γ", "ΔΕΖ")
sClass <- c("Π/Π Β", "N")
```

we may do

```
library(stringr)
myfun <- function(s)
  gsub("\\*", "", trimws(str_match(s, paste0("^\\s*(\\d+)\\s*?(\\w+)\\s*?([\\w ]+)\\s*(", paste(sClub, collapse = "|"),")\\s*(", paste(sClass, collapse = "|"), ")(.*?)\\s*([^ ]*\r)"))[, -1]))

sapply(list(s1, s2), myfun)
#      [,1]                        [,2]          
# [1,] "9"                         "10"          
# [2,] "9875"                      "8954F"       
# [3,] "Γεωργίου Άγγελος Δημήτρης" "Smith John"  
# [4,] "ΑΒ/Γ"                      "ΔΕΖ"         
# [5,] "Π/Π Β"                     "N"           
# [6,] "00:54:05"                  "ΔΕΝ ΕΚΚΙΝΗΣΕ"
# [7,] "167"                       "0"
```

The way it works is just taking into account all your additional information and constructing a long regex. It finishes with erasing `*` and removing leading/trailing whitespace.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Am I right in saying that, if my string had another 3 numbers between `ΑΒ/Γ` and `Π/Π Β` separated by spaces, the regex patern would be replaced by `paste0("^\\s*(\\d+)\\s*?(\\w+)\\s*?([\\w ]+)\\s*(", paste(sClub, collapse = "|"), ")\\s*?(\\w+)\\s*?(\\w+)\\s*?(\\w+)\\s*?(", paste(sClass, collapse = "|"),")(.*?)\\s*([^ ]*\r)")` ? (I never managed to get my head round regex).

Comment: @Constantinos, no problem, glad to help. Yes, it does indeed seem to work!